Trouble in identifying type of function $f-g(x)$ given $f(x)$ & $g(x)$
I came across this question:

If two functions $f,g :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are such that
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x+3&,  \ x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
4x&,  \ x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 
-x&,\ x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
x + \sqrt{5}&, x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
then $(f-g)(x)$ is one-one, onto, both or none.

My attempt:
We know that
$$
(f-g)(x) =\begin{cases}
2x+3&, \ x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
3x - \sqrt{5} &, \ x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
Now the problem is I don't understand how to navigate it further..
The two equations we obtain would have been straight line equations if the domain of each straight line equations was $\mathbb{R}$.
But since it's not, wouldn't it be discontinuous at places?
Normally if it were not a two fold function we could have easily found out if it is a one one function or not by the numerous approaches like horizontal line test, derivative approach,simply looking at the function etc.
Now I am confused, please consider helping or leaving a hint.
Thank you

Hint: It would be convenient if $f-g$ sent rationals to rationals and irrationals to irrationals.  It does send rationals to rationals.  Does it send irrationals to irrationals?

Hints. (1) Compute $(f-g)(0)$ and $(f-g)!\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{5}\right)$; (2) Is there $x$ such that $(f-g)(x)=-\sqrt{5}$?

$h:=f-g$ is clearly bijective from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb Q$ and from $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ to $A:=h(\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q)$. So, it would be one-one iff $A\cap\Bbb Q=\varnothing$, and onto iff $A\supseteq\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. Prove that it is none.

@EricTowers I thought about that too but failed to come up with many counter examples except maybe x being $\frac{√5} {3}$ so we'd get the functional value as 0.. For the rest I believe it does send irrationals to irrationals..

@Gonçalo well yeah those two do give the same functional values. So its not a one one function. Is there a more intutive method for this? I feel like if the function was more complex it would take a lot of brute force to find the ans
